# Pycord message.content is empty

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I'm playing around with the Discord API and noticed that I can't access the content of a message.

This is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'My Name' in message.author.name:
        print(f'Author: {message.author.name}')
        print(f'Content: {message.content}')
        print(f'Clean_Content: {message.clean_content}')
        print(f'System_Content: {message.system_content}')

client.run(TOKEN, bot=False)
```

*Note that the token and my username are kept private in this post for obvious reasons.*

This is the output that I get, no matter the message:

```
Author: My Name
Content: 
Clean_Content: 
System_Content:
```

As you can see I have also tried the clean_content and system_content attributes. However, none of them show the actual message. I've also tried to use a bot account and that surprisingly worked, but I want this to work with my own account. Is the problem that Discord does not intent private clients to read messages or did I miss something fundamental?

Answer (score 13):

As Matt mentioned, user bots are not supported. However, your problem may be related to intents instead. You might try using the following lines:

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

See also:

- https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/intents.html#privileged-intents
- https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/intents.html#message-content-intent

Answer (score 10):

You can solve this by enabling the `MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT` for your bot in the Discord Developer Panel.

```py
import os
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
import discord 



# This example requires the 'message_content' privileged intent to function.


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
            await message.reply('Hello!', mention_author=True)


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True



def main():
  client = MyClient(intents=intents)
  client.run(TOKEN)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This is an example with reply in the [documentation](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/reply.py)

Answer (score 1):

Discord selfbots are no longer supported, you might have to use discord.ext which has support for them still. It seems using discord.py message.content will always be empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just read a tweet of the official Discord Twitter account that says that selfbots are not allowed and will be terminated. Even though I obviously didn't intend to use it in a harmful way, I will respect their public stance on the matter. Yet it confuses me that some of the code still works. For example, sending messages is entirely possible, while reading them isn't. Anyway, I guess my endeavors will end here

Comment: It was for me as well. After adding intents.message_content = True as in Augustins answer it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

you have to go into the discord developer portal and generate a URL checking bot and message.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Discord Developer Portal, go to the Bot tab on the left sidebar, under Privileged Gateway Intents, enable Server Members Intent and Message Content Intent.

[image: Screenshot]